# Date ISO Custom format

Tags: entities

My Drupal offers only three types of rendering a Date ISO field (Display management in Content Type admin panel). What if I want to see my date in a different way? Is there any way to set my own formatter?

Second question. Is there any possibility to indicate while calling render(...) or field_view_value(...) (or anywhere else) what formatter to use? For example, I want for specific set of nodes to show not brief date variant but a full one. How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved that!

in admin/config/regional/date-time there is an ability to add "date type" (there are three default ones, brief, medium ad full format) as well as to add custom format pattern in PHP date()-style for any "date type". Sweet!

Answer (score 1):

There are two thing to do for the date format:

First create a date format (admin/config/regional/date-time/formats/add): this where you define how the date will be display and a simple PHP string date format is all you need something like 'm/d/Y' will show the date as 08/20/2012.

Once the date format is added you can use it on any "Date Type" (admin/config/regional/date-time) or you can create your own date type and assign the date format to it.

To display different date formats depending on what view of node is you have multiple options:

1. Use panels, views, context or display suite and format the date to your date type or date format
2. Edit or create a template for your node type (node--CONTENT-TYPE.tpl.php if D7 or node-CONTENT-TYPE.tpl.php if D6) and use the format_date function to format it.

   if ($teaser) {
   format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i O'));
   } else {
   format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'H:i O Y-m-d'));
   }

OR using your date type:

```
if ($teaser) {
format_date($node->created, 'DATE-TYPE'));
} else {
format_date($node->created, 'DATE-TYPE'));
}
```

Comment: This not an answer to my question, because it was in essence about field rendering and on top of everything unfortunately `format_date ` worls with UNIX timestamps whereas Date (ISO) module stores values in varchar format. But still many thanks for your efforts=)